# sanitizing unsafe URL when local video played in angular with html 5 video tag

Tags: javascript, angular

When the local video is played in html5 video tag.It throws warning as unsafe URL and video content is not playing.

sanitizing the URL with`domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)`in angular still has the same issue

[image]

Added the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uodypm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Please help me out..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use binding in video source element

```
<video *ngIf="playerSrc" width="100%" autoplay="autoplay" controls style="margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <source [src]="playerSrc" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5zawg?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced similar kind of issue for video and here's a way how I resolved it. You can set SRC in HTML like mentioned below to resolve unsafe data issue for image/video.

```
<video *ngIf="playerSrc" width="100%" autoplay="autoplay" controls 
   style="margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
   <source [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(src)" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Bind src like this:  **[src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(src)"**